# SQL WHERE Clause Logic

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with the logic. I am confused, This is the thing:

I have a sort thing. Users select 2 tags: `Tag1` and `Tag2`.

- Tag1 is required, Tag2 is optional.
- If Only Tag 1 is selected, then it shows all the rows which have tag 1
- If Tag1 + Tag2 is selected, it shows all the rows which have tag 1 AND tag 2

This is the logic, I use and it works perfectly fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE tag1 IN ('$tag1','$tag2') $andor tag2 IN ('$tag1','$tag2')  ";
```

Here `$andor`'s value will be `AND`, if both tags are selected. If only 1 tag is selected, it's value will be `OR`

User send `tag1` and `tag2` values via GET method PHP.

---

**The problem is:** Now, I want to add Tag3. But user will not be allowed to select the value of tag3. I will just enter the value of tag3 in the database column. This is What, I want `Tag3` to do

- If a user select a value in `tag1` but it is not present in tag1, but present in tag3. So, it will show tag3 results.
- If a user select two values from `tag1` and `tag2`. And only 1 value match from that, but the missing value which do not match is present in tag3, then the result will be shown.

2 Examples to explain it better:

This is the database table looks like:

```
ID     Tag1     Tag2        Tag3

1      Soup    shampoo      Biscuit

2      Cake    Pizza        Burger 

3      Pizza   Soup         Ice Cream
```

Example 1:  User `selects Biscuit in tag1, and tag2 = nothing.`

Here, I want to show Row I Here, because tag3 contains Biscuit

Example 2: User `selects Cake in tag 1 and Burger in tag2.`

Here, I want to show row 2, because it contain Cake and Burger in tag3

What is the logic, which i need to use? I am not sure, if it is trivial logic or big. If it is big, please, give me some idea, by which I can figure it out.

Comment: This seems like a database design issue to me. My assumption is you want to seperate your tags out of the main row data. This one table would potentially become 3: Items, Tags, ItemTags. This will allow an unlimited number of tags to be added to an item, and a user can search a tag and return all items. If a user search multiple tags (again this wouldnt need to be limited) you query could just become a simple WHERE AND with an AND statement for every tag.

Comment: I only want user to send maximum 2 tags. I do not completely understand, How my new database design should be. I did not add many items in the database till now, I can change it. Can you **please** explain more.

Comment: All i can recommend is looking into SQL many-to-many relationships. I would say what you are aiming for is.. a single item row/record, a single tag row/record, a join table allowing for multiple tags to be assigned to single items. The number of tags you limit this search would not affect this db design